# Ubuntuでネットワークが突然つながらなくなりました

Tags: linux

ubuntuサーバーにsshで接続していましたが、接続できなくなってしまいました。
サーバーを確認すると、有線ケーブルが外れていたので、さしなおしました。
さしなおした直後にpingを飛ばしてみると、反応がありましたが、ssh接続は

```
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused
```

となったため、サーバーを直接操作しようとしました。
ところが、モニターが映らなかったため、サーバーの電源を落とし、再起動しました。
そこからpingを飛ばしても反応がなく、インターネットにつながらなくなりました。

[試したこと]

- 有線のケーブルを変える
- usb経由で無線接続
- 他のLANポートにさしなおす

[現状]

- [こちらのサイト](https://qiita.com/hatt0519/items/06ac708f08d9570f2b93)にあるコマンド

```
lspci | grep 'Ethernet\|Network'
```

では何も出力しなかった。

```
$ ifconfig
br-6b3714642537: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.23.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.23.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:e8ff:fe5b:f871  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:e8:5b:f8:71  txqueuelen 0  (イーサネット)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 137  bytes 12812 (12.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-d5f433673159: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.24.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.24.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:fdff:fe32:4d67  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:fd:32:4d:67  txqueuelen 0  (イーサネット)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 143  bytes 13522 (13.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:f2ff:fe78:8198  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:f2:78:81:98  txqueuelen 0  (イーサネット)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 145  bytes 13712 (13.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (ローカルループバック)
        RX packets 4666  bytes 362510 (362.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4666  bytes 362510 (362.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth44be08b: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::888c:47ff:fe3f:434d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 8a:8c:47:3f:43:4d  txqueuelen 0  (イーサネット)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 223  bytes 21264 (21.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth45f1676: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::18d3:acff:fe26:8bf8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 1a:d3:ac:26:8b:f8  txqueuelen 0  (イーサネット)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 213  bytes 19891 (19.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth8a35a3e: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::285a:2fff:fe74:8711  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 2a:5a:2f:74:87:11  txqueuelen 0  (イーサネット)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 222  bytes 21251 (21.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethaa51673: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::3459:cdff:fe4e:dc5f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 36:59:cd:4e:dc:5f  txqueuelen 0  (イーサネット)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 224  bytes 21393 (21.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network:0               
       詳細: イーサネット interface
       物理ID: 2
       論理名: veth45f1676
       シリアル: 1a:d3:ac:26:8b:f8
       サイズ: 10Gbit/s
       性能: __________________ physical
       設定: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:1
       詳細: イーサネット interface
       物理ID: 3
       論理名: veth44be08b
       シリアル: 8a:8c:47:3f:43:4d
       サイズ: 10Gbit/s
       性能: __________________ physical
       設定: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:2
       詳細: イーサネット interface
       物理ID: 4
       論理名: veth8a35a3e
       シリアル: 2a:5a:2f:74:87:11
       サイズ: 10Gbit/s
       性能: __________________ physical
       設定: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:3
       詳細: イーサネット interface
       物理ID: 5
       論理名: docker0
       シリアル: 02:42:f2:78:81:98
       性能: __________________ physical
       設定: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=yes multicast=yes
  *-network:4
       詳細: イーサネット interface
       物理ID: 6
       論理名: br-6b3714642537
       シリアル: 02:42:e8:5b:f8:71
       性能: __________________ physical
       設定: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.23.0.1 link=yes multicast=yes
  *-network:5
       詳細: イーサネット interface
       物理ID: 7
       論理名: br-d5f433673159
       シリアル: 02:42:fd:32:4d:67
       性能: __________________ physical
       設定: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.24.0.1 link=yes multicast=yes
  *-network:6
       詳細: イーサネット interface
       物理ID: 8
       論理名: vethaa51673
       シリアル: 36:59:cd:4e:dc:5f
       サイズ: 10Gbit/s
       性能: __________________ physical
       設定: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
```

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

どなたかお力添えいただいたおかげでないでしょうか。

Comment: すでに解決していることと思いますが、
UbuntuサーバからLAN内の別のサーバにpingを打った場合に応答がありますか？
インターネット上の別のサーバにpingを打った場合はどうでしょう？ Ubuntuサーバで自機へのssh接続ログインはできますか？

Comment: sshd起動していないか、firewalldが起き上がったか。
`service sshd status`
`service firewalld status`
`service iptables status`
をそれぞれ確認することからですかね。あれ？SELinuxってUbuntuにありましたっけ？あるなら`getenforced`もですね。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントしていただき非常にありがたいのですが、問題はすでにubuntuを入れなおすことで解決しました。

一応、入れなおした時参考にしたサイトを共有しておきます。

boot用のusbの作成
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

ubuntuのisoファイルのダウンロード
https://ubuntu.com/download

boot用のusbからubuntuを入れる方法
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview